# My nib will not load

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

For some reason my nib wont load after the homeButton is pressed.  However, the NSLogs are executed properly.

```
- (IBAction)homePressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"hi");
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"rewardViewController" owner:self options:nil];
    NSLog(@"hey");
}
```

Anyone know what's wrong with this code?

thanks!

Comment: The "for some reason" is that you don't do anything with the nib after loading it. The UI objects will be created, they're just not displayed. Maybe you just want to iterate over the array this method returns and add its objects as subviews to something visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing syntactically wrong with your code, but I suspect that you may have misunderstood what loadNibNamed is going to do for you. If you are trying to change screens by loading a new nib file then you want to explore UINavigationController.

Your code would look something more like this:

```
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerName" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

If you really did intend to use loadNibNamed like you have above you need to assign it to something to make it useful. For example if your nib contains an instance of a UIViewController you might do something like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"rewardViewController" owner:self options:nil];
```

This would create a new instance of a UIViewController with the contents of your nib file. You could then do whatever it is that you wanted to with that UIViewController.

Comment: I really appreciate providing the correct code for me.  Unfortunately neither solution is working for me

Comment: It's possible that your view might not have a UINavigationController depending on how you set it up. If that is the case the line: [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]; won't do anything for you. You'll have to create the navigation controller too. You can read more about UINavigationControllers here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Okay that might be it.  I tried using the same code but loading a different view which worked.  So ill have to double check everything.  Thanks Mike

Comment: im such an idiot.  Im not even going to explain what I did wrong.  I would die of embarrassment

Comment: Welcome to the club. We've all been there.